# How to display image keep ratio in editor

Tags: html, css, editor, image-size

I have a div container to display content which is inputed from editor.

In editor, I upload an image and I want to display this image in that div container also keep image ratio?

Can I do it? Can I get imaze size which I uploaded into editor?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you give `width: 100%;` to image, height will adjust automatically due to `height: auto;` style.

if you need anvanced settings read down below:

if you have and img tag with source, you can get `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight`, so you can make a div containing this image and give it proportional sizes.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <img class='img' src='./photo.png' />
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 0 57%;
  position: absolute;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

you can change this 'padding: 0 0 57%' part to whatever you want. for ex, you can set it with javascript:

```
wrapper.style.padding = '0 0 ' + img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight * 100 + '%;';
```

in this case if `.wrapper` width cahanges, height also changes automatically.